# Python Numpy: np.array converts list values with string lengths longer than 30 to '<str_, len() = ##>'

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, output

I have a pythonList of strings:

```
pythonList= ['Pricing1', 'Expense_Inflation_Rate_Annual.fac', 'Vertical', 'MNT_INFL_PC']
```

When I try to access all the strings by index like `pythonList[1]` they work just fine.

I converted the array into a `numpyArray` so I could use the `np.where` function, but now when I try to access all the strings like `numpyArray[1]` the `'Expense_Inflation_Rate_Annual.fac'` value now holds `'<str_, len() = 33>'` instead while the other 3 work as intended.

My code for the conversion is simply:

```
numpyArray = np.array(pythonList)
```

Edit:

For more context I am using Python 3.9.2 and have discovered with testing that numpy does not like strings longer than 30 characters and anything more than 30 gets the <str_, len() = ##> input.

Here is the code I used to read in pythonList:

```
    with open (r'c:\\temp\{}'.format(resultFileName)) as lp:
        fileData = lp.readlines()
    pythonList= []
    for row in fileData:
        pythonList.append(row.split(','))

    numpyArray= np.array(pythonList)
```

If anyone could provide more detail on this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I tried this code: import numpy as np

lst = ['Pricing1', 'Expense_Inflation_Rate_Annual.fac', 'Vertical', 'MNT_INFL_PC']

arr = np.array(lst)

print(arr[1])

Comment: It worked very well, arr[1] prints 'Expense_Inflation_Rate_Annual.fac' without any odd output

Comment: That is a list, not an array

Comment: That is what you wrote in your question.

Comment: In any case, please provide a [mcve]. It would be helpful to know the version of bumpy/python

Comment: Thanks everyone for the helpful comments, learned that lists and arrays are different and provided code I used to create the pythonList for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [114]: pythonList = [
     ...:     "Pricing1",
     ...:     "Expense_Inflation_Rate_Annual.fac",
     ...:     "Vertical",
     ...:     "MNT_INFL_PC",
     ...: ]
In [115]: np.array(pythonList)
Out[115]: 
array(['Pricing1', 'Expense_Inflation_Rate_Annual.fac', 'Vertical',
       'MNT_INFL_PC'], dtype='<U33')
```

It's not clear where you get the `'<str_, len() = 33>'`.  If I index that string, the result is an object of `type` str_` and length 33.

```
In [116]: np.array(pythonList)[1]
Out[116]: 'Expense_Inflation_Rate_Annual.fac'
In [117]: type(np.array(pythonList)[1])
Out[117]: numpy.str_
In [118]: len(np.array(pythonList)[1])
Out[118]: 33
```

From `pythonList` we get something similar, except the type is slightly different:

```
In [119]: type(pythonList[1])
Out[119]: str
In [120]: len(pythonList[1])
Out[120]: 33
```

A Python list contains `str` objects that vary in length.  When converted to a numpy array, they are stored as bytes with a `Un` dtype.  Here `U33` is the length of the longest string in the input.

You mention using `where`, but don't elaborate.

`numpy` arrays of strings don't have a lot of advantages relative to lists of strings.

Comment: How do I index the array and not get an object as you stated? I simply want the string value and not an object that explains me the type and length of the value.

I use the np.where later on in the code, but it doesn't matter because this issue arises before then. I only mentioned the np.where to give context to why I was using the numpy array and not simply the python list.

Comment: Are you running this in some IDE or other special environment.  What I showed is from a `ipython` interactive session.  `Out[116]` IS the string that I get from the array.  I've never seen output that looks like ''<str_, len() = 33>'', though I understand what it means.

Comment: Yes, using Visual Studio Code. You just solved the issue! It's only in the debug window, it's not actually happening. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the collection of `numpy.str_` elements, you need to use `str()` to get the actual string. For example:

```
pythonList= ['Pricing1', 'Expense_Inflation_Rate_Annual.fac', 'Vertical', 'MNT_INFL_PC']
numpyArray = np.array(pythonList)
print(str(numpyArray[1]))
```